# string to associative array conversion

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I've been struggling with this for a few days and wanted to throw it out there and see if someone has any ideas.

Basically I have a string e.g

```
1) "/0/bar"

2) "/build/0/foo/1"
```

and need to convert this into a multidimensional array

```
1) $result[0][bar] 
2) $result[build][0][foo][1]
```

So far I've tried:

```
$query = "/build/0/foo/1";
$queryAr = [];
$current = &$queryAr;
$keys = explode("/", $query);

foreach($keys as $key) {
  @$current = &$current[$key];
}

$current = $value;
```

quieting the output is a pretty hacky way to achive this...

Answer (score 1):

You need to trim the first `/` of the string. [live demo](https://eval.in/841468).

```
<?php
$query = "/build/0/foo/1";
$queryAr = [];
$current = &$queryAr;
$keys = explode("/", trim($query, '/'));

foreach($keys as $key) {
  @$current = &$current[$key];
}

$current = $value;
print_r($queryAr);
```

Comment: Seems to be the way to go, but why exactly you have $current = $value? Would be good to have unset($current) to avoid problems if you use $current for any other purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a recursive function version:

```
$query = "/build/0/foo/1";
print_r($result = buildNestedArray(explode('/', trim($query, '/'))));

function buildNestedArray($keys)
{
    $k = current($keys);

    $result = [$k => 'DONE'];
    array_shift($keys);
    if (sizeof($keys) > 0) { $result[$k] = buildNestedArray($keys); }

    return $result;
}
```

output: `Array ( [build] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [foo] => Array ( [1] => DONE ) ) ) )`