# How to set a list of values as keys in a multidimensional associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to convert a list of values such as:

```
$foo = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

into a list of traversing array keys such as:

```
$bar['a']['b']['c'] = 123;
```

How I can create an associative array which keys are based on a set values stored in another array?

Comment: Have you tried something? Post your effort too.

Comment: You can use a for loop to achieve that.

Comment: Where does the 123 come from? If the input was `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];` would that make the output `$bar['a']['b']['c']['d']`? And would it still be 123? Or 1234?

Comment: The value '123' would be set at the end very end after creating the keys of the array

Comment: Similar with this one [string to associative array conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45504040/6521116)

Comment: Also similar: [PHP Convert single dimensional array to nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46717139/php-convert-single-dimensional-array-to-nested-array)

Comment: And near-exact duplicate: `PHP flat array to nested [“a”, “b”, “c”] to [“a” =>[“b”=>[“c”]]] [closed]` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30364917/php-flat-array-to-nested-a-b-c-to-a-b-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it with reference. Try this code, [live demo](https://eval.in/920961)

```
<?php
$foo = ['a', 'b', 'c']; 
$array = [];
$current = &$array;
foreach($foo as $key) {
  @$current = &$current[$key];
}
$current = 123;
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
$foo = ['a', 'b', 'c']; 
$val = '123';
foreach (array_reverse($foo) as $k => $v) {
    $bar = [$v => $k ? $bar : $val];
}
```

We are iterating over the array in reverse and assigning the innermost value first, then building the array from the inside out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option: Create a temporary parsable string (by extracting the first value, then appending the remaining values as square bracket wrapped strings), call `parse_str()`, and set the output variable as `$bar`.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/02cb0633d286a65c6d73ff715ea6b8af72881510))

```
$foo = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$val=123;

parse_str(array_shift($foo).'['.implode('][',$foo)."]=$val",$bar);
// built string: `a[b][c]=123`
var_export($bar);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'a' => 
  array (
    'b' => 
    array (
      'c' => '123',
    ),
  ),
)
```

---

If that first method feels too hack-ish, the following recursive method is a stable approach:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6fbac38d5b1a025e8e809dc193dea9b22f17a4b1))

```
function nest_assoc($keys,$value){
    return [array_shift($keys) => (empty($keys) ? $value : nest_assoc($keys,$value))];
    //      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--------------------------------------------------------extract leading key value, modify $keys
    //  check if any keys left-----^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //  no more keys, use the value---------------^^^^^^
    //  recurse to write the subarray contents-------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}

$foo=['a','b','c'];
$val=123;

var_export(nest_assoc($foo,$val));
// same output
```